# How i save and display images perfectly without cut from top or bottom paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, crop

Hi i am using paperclip for saving images my model is below

```
   class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_attached_file :snap, :styles => {:banner => "950x505", :large => "1200x1200", :medium => "363x569"}
     belongs_to :product
   end
```

If i upload images of 200x200 and display image using image tag of large size then image is weird and stretched out.

And if i follow this code of model

```
     class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_attached_file :snap, :styles => {:banner => "950x505#", :large => "1200x1200#", :medium => "363x569#"}
     belongs_to :product
   end
```

Mean using "#" sign with sizes of image and display large image. then image not stretched out but some portion cut out from upper or bottom portion.

How i can upload images that fit out perfectly without stretched out or cutout from anyside?

Comment: are you sure it is cut? maybe it is your css problem. Try to view the image link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upload a low resolution image and try to enlarge it, it's but obvious that the image will distort or pixelate.  A better option would be to upload highest res picture (in your case may be 1280px  and then apply the styles you already have.

Answer (score 2):

Please can you try this

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/

Answer (score 0):

Well, what if you try:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :snap, :styles => {:banner => "950x505>", :large => "1200x1200>", :medium => "363x569>"}
  belongs_to :product
end
```

IIRC, that will downsize any image proportionally to fit within the bounds specified, without cropping, and leave smaller images alone, as they already fit within the bounds specified.

I use:

```
class Image < GenericModel
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => {:fit => "800x600>", :thumb => "100x100>"}
  blah blah blah
end
```

to specify a "fit" and "thumb" version.

If an uploaded image is portrait 400 by 300, the "thumb" will be 100 tall and 75 wide to maintain the proportions.  If the image is 300 by 400, the "thumb" is 75 by 100.

No stretching of smaller images occur for the "fit" either, the image remains at 400 by 300 (or vice-versa).